# ¿Hay forma de convertir una imagen generada en ABC music notation a OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy generando imágenes de partituras mediante Jupyter y ABC music notation.

```
%load_ext jupyter_abc

%%abc
%%score (R1 R2) (L)
V:R1
[cc']2 z ((3g/a/b/ [cc']2) z ((3g/a/b/ | [cc']2) z2 z2 z c | (c3 B d3 c) | (g4 f2) z2 |
V:R2
x8 | x8 | G8- | G6 z2 |
V:L clef=bass middle=d
[cc']2 z ((3g/a/b/ [cc']2) z ((3g/a/b/ | [cc']2) z2 z4 | ([d'f']4 [c'e']4) | [bd']6 z2 |
```

La salida de esto es una imagen (aún no estoy seguro pero creo que es SVG, sin embargo también podría ser PNG).
La cuestión es que necesito acceder a los pixeles de esta imagen para averiguar si es negro o blanco.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
pixel= image[200, 550]
print pixel
```

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo paso la imagen desde ABC a OpenCV?

Comment: Para eso tendrías que descargar la imagen y energía y luego leerla con OpenCv

Comment: ¿No hay forma de cargarla en el clipboard? Son imágenes pequeñas. Así como un string de bytes.

Comment: Bueno yo no conozco una forma